# Not executing SSJS code in eventHandler with complete refreshMode in XPages

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs, ibm-domino

It's been 3 weeks since I've been struggling with this problem

onClick eventHandler rejects to show any signs of being working properly when it goes hand in hand with  `refreshMode="complete"`

The code is below:

```
<xp:button id="begginYOU"
            style="float: right; margin-right:20px;"
            value="Send">

            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" refreshMode="complete"
                  submit="true">

                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                print("I will never get this message printed with complete refreshMode");

            }]]>
                </xp:this.action>

            </xp:eventHandler>

</xp:button>
```

I've tried everything - setting properties of `id` (on eventHandler itself), adding CSJS code  which returns true (the message which I've added to console.log was always printed btw), setting `disableValidators` to `true`

I've even tried to remove all the inputs and just leave this one button on the entire page - nothing helped

Whenever I click the button - all I get is just a `loading` next to the tab's icon in the browser for just half a second and nothing, literally NOTHING happens

It ONLY works with refreshMode and execMode set to `partial` (provided that I provide ids respectively) but I have no idea why

It really drives me around the bend

But anyway I hope to receive experts' opinion on that problem, because I've run out of ideas

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Does it work in a blank XPage with no data sources attached?

Comment: Actually, it worked after removing <xp:this.data> block

Comment: Yes, I suspect that some backend form validation cancels out the refresh

Comment: What in particular do you think cancels it out? The data resource doesn't seem to be any input

Comment: Install the logreader.nsf database. It helped me on many occasions, for there may be errors that stay invisible from the (standard) outside. Another approach: gradually remove elements from your page until your button works.

Comment: And what's in that data block? Anything that, when being recalculated, errors out?

Comment: Hello I recommented out the block which contains xp:dominoDocument and it seems it broke the button